# Rigidbody based character controller

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I makeíng a charater controller rigidboy based! The movement is all great but not when the player tries going up/down slops. When the player walk on a slop, the Y axies velocity goes crazy

[Here is a video of what is happening](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NangrK53ts6DAi56uVgjyCeJWEyUJzGK/view?usp=sharing)

Here is my code:

```
[Header("Needed Components")]
[SerializeField] Rigidbody playerRb;
[SerializeField] CapsuleCollider playerCollider;

[Header("Movement")]
[SerializeField] float walkingSpeed;
[SerializeField] float runningSpeed;

[Header("Jump")]
[SerializeField] float jumpForce;
[SerializeField] GroundChecking groundChecking;

[Header("Stair Climbing")]
[SerializeField] LayerMask layerFilter;
[SerializeField] GameObject lowerRay;
[SerializeField] GameObject upperRay;
[SerializeField] float stepHieght;
[SerializeField] float stepSmooth;

// Input
private MovementInputManger playerInput;

private void OnValidate()
{
    // Stair Climbing
    upperRay.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(upperRay.transform.position.x, stepHieght, upperRay.transform.position.z);
}

private void Start()
{
    playerInput = MovementInputManger.Instance;

    Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
    Cursor.visible = false;
}

private void Update()
{
    if (playerInput.PlayerJumpedThisFrame())
        Jump();
}

private void FixedUpdate()
{
    Move();
}

private void Move()
{
    float movingSpeed;
    if (playerInput.IsRunning())
        movingSpeed = runningSpeed;
    else
        movingSpeed = walkingSpeed;

    playerRb.velocity = Vector3.up * playerRb.velocity.y// Y velocity
                        + playerCollider.transform.right * movingSpeed * playerInput.GetPlayerMovement().x // X velocity
                        + playerCollider.transform.forward * movingSpeed * playerInput.GetPlayerMovement().y; // Z velocity

    if (playerRb.velocity.z != 0f || playerRb.velocity.x != 0f)
        stepClimb();
}

private void Jump()
{
    if (groundChecking.IsGrounded())
    {
        playerRb.AddForce(Vector3.up * jumpForce, ForceMode.Impulse);
    }
}


bool hitLower, hitUpper;
private void stepClimb()
{
    if (Physics.Raycast(lowerRay.transform.position, playerCollider.transform.forward, out RaycastHit lowerHit, playerCollider.radius + 0.2f, layerFilter))
    {
        hitLower = true;
        if (!Physics.Raycast(upperRay.transform.position, playerCollider.transform.forward, out RaycastHit upperHit, playerCollider.radius + 0.3f, layerFilter))
        {
            playerRb.position += new Vector3(0f, stepSmooth, 0f);
            hitUpper = true;
        }
        else hitUpper = false;
    }
    else 
    { 
        hitLower = false; 
        hitUpper = false;
    }
}

private void OnDrawGizmos()
{
    if (hitLower)
    {
        Gizmos.color = Color.green;
        Gizmos.DrawLine(lowerRay.transform.position, lowerRay.transform.position + playerCollider.transform.forward * (playerCollider.radius + 0.2f));
    }
    else
    {
        Gizmos.color = Color.red;
        Gizmos.DrawLine(lowerRay.transform.position, lowerRay.transform.position + playerCollider.transform.forward * (playerCollider.radius + 0.2f));
    }


    if (hitUpper)
    {
        Gizmos.color = Color.green;
        Gizmos.DrawLine(upperRay.transform.position, upperRay.transform.position + playerCollider.transform.forward * (playerCollider.radius + 0.3f));
    }
    else
    {
        Gizmos.color = Color.red;
        Gizmos.DrawLine(upperRay.transform.position, upperRay.transform.position + playerCollider.transform.forward * (playerCollider.radius + 0.3f));
    }

}
```

I am kind sure the issue in the move function where i am setting the playerRb velocity, but i have no clue how to fixe it.

I will be greatfull for any help.

Comment: One thing, you should use FixedUpdate instead of Update; second I do not think modifying velocity and position at the same time is a good idea - modifying position is teleporting it can produce issues with colliders; running/moving speed you are applying only on x/z axis - think about walking up a steep hill you would move more up that forward and that is the root cause of your issue

Comment: The Move function is in FixedUodate already and i am only changing the velocity not the position.

Comment: I think @Rafal refers to `playerRb.position += new Vector3(0f, stepSmooth, 0f);` ... ;)

Comment: Sounds like when you are walking on a slope your `transform.forward` also points slightly upwards => you would probably want to always map both `transform.right` and `transform.forward` onto a flat plane first e.g. [`Vector3.ProjectOnPlane(transform.forward, Vector3.up)`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.ProjectOnPlane.html)

Comment: @derHugo didn't work unfortunately. Do you have any other suggistions? Note: The rigidbody rotation is frozen on all axies.

Comment: @TheDarkAbyss I think we would need a better description of `the Y axies velocity goes crazy` ^^ What exactly does that mean?

Comment: @Rafal for single time events using `Update` is actually fine - depending of course what / how exactly is applied in such case. Here it changes the velocity and doesn't directly touch the position so this should be fine and simply applied in the next `FixedUpdate` routine

Comment: @derHugo I have updated the post with a video showing what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever your means to capture the "IsGrounded" data (Raycast or Collision), you need to capture the ground normal.
I suggest separating your local movement velocity and performing a Vector3.ProjectOnPlane passing in your move velocity and ground normal.

Should look something like this:

```
Vector3 movementVelocity = (playerCollider.transform.right * playerInput.GetPlayerMovement().x) + //X direction
                    (playerCollider.transform.forward * playerInput.GetPlayerMovement().y); //Y direction
movementVelocity = Vector3.ClampMagnitude(moveDirection, 1f); //this is simply your relative direction and should not exceed 1 magnitude.
movementVelocity *= movingSpeed; // apply the velocity to the direction

//Your movement velocity should follow the surface plane,
//this will prevent slow movement up slopes and bouncing when going down slopes
movementVelocity = Vector3.ProjectOnPlane(movementVelocity, groundNormal);
movementVelocity -= Vector3.up * playerRb.velocity.y; //preserving the vertical velocity

playerRb.velocity = movementVelocity;
```

I would also suggest setting the y velocity to 0 when performing a stair climb so the velocity doesn't mess with the position being set